# Sharepoint Online - External User and Person (people picker) issue

Tags: people-picker, external-users

All, got an issue with the above, my external users can suddenly no longer add their names into a sharepoint online list.

The people picker resolves and finds them. But then you get “this field can not be left blank”

Help

Answer (score -1):

Had this issue last year on SP 2016 on-prem instalation.
After 1 hour discussion with the system admistrator - some magic with  User Profile Synchronization serivce was done and the the issue was fixed.
Actually i remember that i traced the HTTP request which were related to the loading of the people picker and i found that some of the fields (do not remember which one) were empty.